# Oracle query to get a sequence based on another column

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to frame a query in oracle where I have a table without below data

| ORDER | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| 34905 | 2 |
| 39754 | 5 |

And the output should look like

| NewSequence |
| --- |
| 34905-1 |
| 34905-2 |
| 39754-1 |
| 39754-2 |
| 39754-3 |
| 39754-4 |
| 39754-5 |

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to provide a [mcve] - tl;dr you have to show your work. You can't just post requirements and then leave it up to the Community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of variations based on CONNECT BY:

```
with data(order_num, qty) as (
    select '34905', 2 from dual union all
    select '39754', 5 from dual
)
select order_num || '-' || level as newsequence
from data
connect by level <= qty and prior order_num = order_num 
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
;


with data(order_num, qty) as (
    select '34905', 2 from dual union all
    select '39754', 5 from dual
)
select order_num ||'-'|| column_value as new_sequence
from data,
lateral
(
    select level as column_value from dual
    connect by level <= qty
);
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You will need a domain for generation of the sequence. Here I used a cte with constants, you could use a recursive cte between 1 and max qty (or a numbers table of you have such):

```
with num(n) as ( values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) 
select o.orderno || '-' || cast(num.n as varchar(2))
from num
join orders o
    on o.qty >= num.n
order by o.orderno, n;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qO0QhsyB)

Using a numbers table like

```
insert into numbers (n)
select 1 from dual
union all
select 2 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual
union all
select 4 from dual
union all
select 5 from dual;
```

You can write the query as:

```
select o.orderno || '-' || cast(numbers.n as varchar(2))
from numbers
join orders o
    on o.qty >= numbers.n
order by o.orderno, n;
```

Comment: Although this code works, it only works for version 23c, which is still in beta. This answer probably won't help most users for a few years, so you might want to re-write it using older features.

Comment: Just use a numbers table or connect by for the generator

Comment: Aside from all that: it's a question where the OP has done nothing but provide a set of requirements, without showing any work of their own. Not a question that should be answered. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

That's a row generator of some kind, as you've already been told. Version that works in *lower* Oracle database versions (lower than 23c, I mean) is:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (c_order, qty) as
  2    (select 34905, 2 from dual union all
  3     select 39754, 5 from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select c_order ||'-'|| column_value as new_sequence
  6  from test cross join
  7    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                        connect by level <= qty
  9                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

NEW_SEQUENCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
34905-1
34905-2
39754-1
39754-2
39754-3
39754-4
39754-5

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```